# Iterator for multiple dimension array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for iterator for multiple dimension array that I can iterate through the array easily.
For  example:

```
var multipeArrayLike = [[1,[21,22],3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
var iterator = getIterator(multipeArrayLike)

console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 1 
console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 21
console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 22
console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 3
console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 4
console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 5
....
console.log(iterator.next().value) // should return 8
```

Comment: You need to create recursive function which checks for values if values is an array again call this function with that values else if the values is not array return the value;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator in a way similar to this:

```js
'use strict';

function *flat(a) {
    if (!Array.isArray(a)) {
        yield a;
    } else {
        for (let x of a)
            yield *flat(x);
    }
}

var multipeArrayLike = [[1, [21, 22], 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]


for (let y of flat(multipeArrayLike))
    document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(y,0,3));
```

Comment: If you add `'use strict';` to your example, it will run in Chrome (at least the version I have).

Comment: @FelixKling: works fine here (49.0.2623.110), but added, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I'm still on 48.0.2564.116. It doesn't allow block scoped variables in non-strict mode. Looks like I should upgrade :D